# SQL SERVER job is not executing SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created SSIS by using SSDT 2015 and it is executing properly with in the SSDT tool, but when i try to run the package via SQL Server agent job it gives below error. need help.

Message:

> Executed as user: ISB-CCDEV-MS1\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.1000.169 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  7:24:31 PM 
>   Error: 2019-06-18 19:24:31.85     Code: 0xC001F02A     Source:
>   Package9      Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task
>   "Send Mail Task", type "Microsoft.SendMailTask" due to error
>   0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".  End Error  Error:
>   2019-06-18 19:24:31.85     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: Send Mail Task
>   Description: Failed to load task "Send Mail Task", type "". The
>   contact information for this task is "Send Mail Task; Microsoft
>   Corporation; SQL Server 2017; ? 2017 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights
>   Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".  End
>   Error  Error: 2019-06-18 19:24:31.85     Code: 0xC0010026     Source:
>   Send Mail Task      Description: The task has failed to load. The
>   contact information for this task is "Send Mail Task; Microsoft
>   Corporation; SQL Server 2017; ? 2017 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights
>   Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".  End
>   Error  Error: 2019-06-18 19:24:31.85     Code: 0xC0024107     Source:
>   Send Mail Task      Description: There were errors during task
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2019-06-18 19:24:31.85     Code:
>   0xC0010025     Source: Package9      Description: The package cannot
>   execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.  End Error 
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started: 
>   7:24:31 PM  Finished: 7:24:31 PM  Elapsed:  0.531 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: The message you've posted seems to be telling you the problem here. Considering we can't access your package, and we don't know what it does, I would suggest starting where it suggests: Looking at "Package9" (I suggest more descriptive names) at the task "Send Mail Task".

Comment: this package is sending a simple email to me. [as a test case]

Comment: The problem is with one of the parameters of your `Send Mail Task`. How is it configured?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed. The SQL SERVER installed was not configured with Data tools option while installation, I have reinstalled on existing instance and it worked.

Comment: i am getting the same error.  I am just trying to run the package from my machine in vs19 i dont have sql server installed on my local machine just mssms does mssms have a data tools option that would need to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

We had a SQL job calling a package ( \file\package.dtsx ) failing with the message. I installed the latest CU’s for SQL 2017 (needed if installing IS after installing SQL Data Tools) and installed Integration Services on the SQL server.

Comment: This was specific to the  "SEND MAIL" ssis task.